# Can SQL server and WSUS co-exist on same server?

Tags: sql-server, sql, wsus, desktop

Pardon me if this is a stupid question, but after reading responses from my previous question I'm looking into implementing WSUS on my network.

The box I would likely implement it on runs a relatively small SQL server, and I understand that WSUS uses "Desktop SQL". It would be installed on a Server 2003 / IIS6 machine.

Is there a risk that the Desktop SQL would cause conflicts with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Mainstream support for Server 2003 ended in July of this year.  We all understand that cost may be the deciding factor, but be sure to at least consider the long-term implications of adding new services on a machine that is still running an outdated operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSUS 3.0 will install local Windows Internal Database for you if a compatible version of SQL Server is not installed already. If you plan to use a full SQL Server database, you must use (at a minimum) SQL Server 2005 SP1 on Windows Server 2003, or SQL Server 2005 SP2 on Windows Server 2008.

I have installed WSUS and SQL Server many times on the same server before and never had any problems.

Internal Database does not pose any problems with another instance of SQL Server on the same server to my knowledge.

Comment: So you don't see a problem with them on the same server?

The other option I was thinking about was installing WSUS on a Server 2008 box that I'm configuring for TS Gateway / Virtualized Remote Desktop machine

Comment: I don't recommend installing WSUS on the same server with TS Gateway.

Comment: WSUS is not supported on servers running Terminal Services.

Comment: Well technically it wouldn't be on a machine running TS, just the host machine where a virtual machine is a TS

Comment: I just noticed that WSUS and SQL server instances interacted with each other in some strange way. Whenever I run a job in SQL Server, WSUS database starts consuming CPU, and the job just hangs. I'm not admin, and I do not know the reasons behind, but, be aware. PS. Environment: Windows Server 2012 on virtual machine, and SQL Server 2012 Development edition.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this and it worked fine. This was the environment; Windows Server 2003, WSUS, SQL 2005 Express and we also ran Standard for a while. We eventually had a disaster and made that computer the DC and AD as well. It all ran fine. Until the disaster I had full confidence in the setup. After the disaster I felt is was best to offload the DB. The DB was for ACT a horrid sales force like program.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you use the slimmed down database engine, but WSUS also has the ability to use a real SQL instance.

If you had SQL Server 2005 or 2008, you could use that for the WSUS database instead.

Comment: WSUS 3.0 does not support SQL 2000

Comment: -1 He can't use the existing SQL instance.  WSUS requires SQL 2005, he only has SQL 2000.

Comment: @Luke99, Good catch, I somehow missed the SQL 2000 part. You're 100% Correct. @pipTheGeek - You're half right, it is also supported on SQL Server 2008.